# How to find the row number of swt Table

Tags: java

Anybody please answer my question.
I have an swt table,
for my project purpose i need to know the row number of table cursor positioned.

Comment: i find this answer..usefull....thank you bro...have a nice day..

Answer (score 2):

> simple method use on table: **table.getItemCount()**

```
//create a Table

Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION|SWT.CHECK);

//TableColumn Object:tblclmnNewColumn_1

TableColumn tblclmnNewColumn_1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    tblclmnNewColumn_1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            //click on this column 
            System.out.println("Row Index:"+table.getSelectionIndex());
            System.out.println("Total Row Count:"+table.getItemCount());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little inefficient, but this should do the trick.

From the [Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTable.html)

> int   indexOf(TableItem item) Searches the receiver's list starting at
>   the first item (index 0) until an item is found that is equal to the
>   argument, and returns the index of that item.

> TableItem getRow() Returns the row over which the TableCursor is
>   positioned.

```
table.indexOf(cursor.getRow())
```

You may have to add 1 if you don't want to see row zero.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is very usefull for me.